# Drools : How to update Arraylist?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, drools, jbpm

I am stuck in middle of something,
I am trying to update Object in drools session as code given, but it could not gets update.

```
rule "Abc"
salience 1
when
         a:A()
    then
         ArrayList al = a.getAllItems();
         for(int i =0;i<a.getAllItems().size;i++)
         {
             B b = new B();
             al.add(b);
         }
         a.setAllItems(al);
         update(a);
end
```

Any suggession or help from you will help me to go ahead....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'd started with simplified code like below:

```
rule "Abc"
salience 1
when
  a:A()
then
  modify($a) { myMethod(); }         
end



public class A {
  public void myMethod() {
    for(Object obj : getAllItems()) {
      B b = new B();
      // ...
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```